# How to prevent plugins from being uninstalled

Tags: permissions

The following filter works great for preventing plugins from being deactivated...

`add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', 'disable_plugin_deactivation', 10, 4 )`;

with...

```
// array_key_exists( 'edit', $actions )...
// array_key_exists( 'deactivate', $actions )...
```

...But is there a similar filter or array_key, that prevents plugins from displaying their uninstall link on the plugins.php file?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about editors as in "people that just want to edit articles", or editors as in "users with the role editor"? The latter should not be able to delete plugins imho.

Comment: Allow me to revise my original question....I overlooked my objective...

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way for that. You might be able to use `register_deactivation_hook()` to hook into the deactivation event and then just use `activate_plugin()` to immediately reactivate it. It's not the cleanest of ways, but should be pretty straightforward (if I'm not missing something major).

Comment: please forgive me janh, allow me to revise my question once again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same filter, just remove the `delete` key of the $actions array. If you want to remove the "delete" link for the plugin "myplugin", you'd go for something like this:

```
add_filter("plugin_action_links", function($actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context) {
    if($plugin_file == "myplugin/myplugin.php") {
        unset($actions["delete"]);
    }
    return $actions;
}, 10, 4);
```

Obviously, you cannot put this into the plugin itself, since it will have been deactivated or the delete link will not show up (link to deactivate the plugin will be in its place). Also, be aware that this will only remove the link, it will not stop a determined user with the appropriate privileges from sending that request manually.

Comment: Your logic makes perfect sense...but how did you know that the `$actions[]` value was `"delete"`  is there a list of values I can also view/access?

Comment: I didn't know a filter, so I tried to find out where the links are crafted and what filter I might use to influence that. The `single_row()` method in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php` does handle that, and includes the possible actions in an array `$actions`: deactivate, activate, details, edit, and delete.